# Laravel - force pagination links to show even if there is only a single page

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I'm working with [laravel pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination), however I wish to display the pagination links regardless of if there is only a single page, or multiple pages.

Currently, it is only displayed if there are multiple pages of results.

Eloquent Call

```
$products = Product::where('username', Sentry::getUser()->username)->paginate(25);
```

and then displayed in the view using

```
{!! $products->links() !!}
```

How can I force Laravel to display it when there is only a single page?

Comment: Implement it yourself.  Simply read the documentation you linked and then create your own Blade view with your collection like: `@include('layout.component.pagination', ['paginated' => $products])`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - the documentation does not have anything on how to create custom pagination markup. Can you provide a link to the documentation please?

Comment: Well under **Additional Helper Methods** you are shown a few methods that you can use from the Paginator.  You could simply create your own view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way, because it's hardcoded. However you could extend [`SimpleBootstrapThreePresenter`](https://github.com/illuminate/pagination/blob/master/SimpleBootstrapThreePresenter.php) and override [`hasPages()`](https://github.com/illuminate/pagination/blob/master/SimpleBootstrapThreePresenter.php#L26) method:

```
public function hasPages()
{
    return true;
}
```

Instead of:

```
public function hasPages()
{
    return $this->paginator->hasPages() && count($this->paginator->items()) > 0;
}
```

Comment: Another documentation about the pagination: http://devdocs.io/laravel~5.2/api/5.2/illuminate/pagination/paginator#method_hasPages

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I created another answer with my complete code as i'm not sure how to get it in a comment.

Answer (score 5):

Publish pagination views:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

This command will place the views in the `resources/views/vendor/pagination` directory.

Default view is `bootstrap-4.blade.php` and just delete the `@if ($paginator->hasPages())` in this file.

Comment: This was way easier, if you ask me! Allows me to use in-built classes etc, the only thing we had to do was publish (which we already had done, for an unrelated change). Thank you very much! BTW: For me, the default file was `default.blade.php`, but we're on Laravel 6, so that might be why.

Answer (score 3):

Following [Alexey Mezenin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36792506/6239598), I extended the `BootstrapThreePresenter` class:

```
<?php namespace App\Extend;

use Illuminate\Pagination\BootstrapThreePresenter;

class CustomPaginationLinks extends BootstrapThreePresenter {

    public function hasPages()
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

And was then able to render in the view like so:

```
{!! with(new App\Extend\CustomPaginationLinks($products))->render() !!}
```

Comment: You should really be using [Dependency Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) instead of `{!! with(new App\Extend\CustomPaginationLinks($products))->render() !!}`